# Angular-ui modal and phalcon, error sending data into modal controller from $http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, phalcon

I'm using the angular-ui modal directive.
And tried to fetch data from my phalcon controller, but I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: Phalcon\Di::$_default in C:\xampp\htdocs\cofiso\app\library\Base\Services.php:9 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Di->__construct() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cofiso\app\library\Base\Services.php(9): Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault->__construct() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\cofiso\public\index.php(25): Base\Services->__construct(Object(Phalcon\Config\Adapter\Ini)) #3 {main} Next Error: Access to undeclared static property: Phalcon\Di::$_default in C:\xampp\htdocs\cofiso\app\library\Base\Services.php on line 9
```

Here is my code:

```
$scope.edit_prest = function(index){

 var idCell = $scope.prestamos[index];

    ServicesPost.getPrestamo(idCell).then(function(data){
        $scope.promesa = data;
    },function(error){
        alert(error);
    });

    $scope.items = [$scope.Cliente,$scope.id,$scope.Tasa];

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'prestamo/edit/'+idCell,
                controller: 'InstanceCtrl_Edit',
                 size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {                        
                      return $scope.items;
                    },

                    cliente: function(){
                        return $scope.promesa;  //ServicesPost.getPrestamo(idCell);
                    }
                }
    });


}
```

and my factory ServicesPost:

```
myApp.factory('ServicesPost', function($http) {
  var myService = {
      getPrestamo: function(idCell){


      var promesa = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'prestamo/dataPrestamo',
        data: "idCell="+idCell
      }).then(function successCall(response) {

        return response.data;

      }, function errorCall(error){
         console.log(error);
    });

   return promesa;

     }
   };
 return myService;
});
```

And my modal Always shows this error: (Click in the link it's the img to see the error)

[image: Message in the modal, it's an error of phalcon (click here)]

here is my code PHP:

```
public function dataPrestamoAction(){
if($this->request->isPost() == true){

    $this->view->disable();
    $idperfil = $this->request->getPost("idperfil");

    $this->response->setJsonContent(array('data' => $idperfil));
    $this->response->setStatusCode(200, "OK POST EDIT PRESTAMO");
    $this->response->send();
}
```

}

next: Here should show me the .volt view

```
public function editAction($idprestamo)
{
 if($this->request->isGet() == true){

    $this->view->setRenderLevel(
        View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW
    ); 


 }
}
```

And this is my code Requested of my file Base/Service.php

I actually do not know what to change from that Base/Service.php code

As a programmer I make a tremendous effort to understand, I am Spanish speaking and it is a bit complicated because all the codes are in English.

Any help is welcome. Thank. 
And excuse my bad English.

```
  namespace Base;

 class Services extends \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault
{
  public function __construct($config)
  {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setShared('config', $config);
    $this->bindServices();
}

protected function bindServices()
{
    $reflection = new \ReflectionObject($this);
    $methods = $reflection->getMethods();

    foreach ($methods as $method) {

        if ((strlen($method->name) > 10) && (strpos($method->name, 'initShared') === 0)) {
            $this->set(lcfirst(substr($method->name, 10)), $method->getClosure($this));
            continue;
        }

        if ((strlen($method->name) > 4) && (strpos($method->name, 'init') === 0)) {
            $this->set(lcfirst(substr($method->name, 4)), $method->getClosure($this));
        }

    }

}
}
```

And intend to solve this error for several days.

Could anyone help me please. Thank.

I hope this is good. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: An error with the PHP code not with the Angular code, so post your php code as well.

Comment: I think that this is an issue that has been resolved. Can you download the latest Phalcon version and try again please?

Comment: Is something strange because when he commented one and only solves a normal one works. 
That is, if I put only the dialog, normal shows me the content without error, And if you put only the normal factory service shows me the data without error, And if I put both there is the problem error. 
That's why I think it's not a php problem. 
But I'll put it down here anyway

Comment: And if I work with the updated version of phalcon. 
And if there is post solved the problem lei everything needed but not to solve my problem

Comment: Can you also supply the source for `app/library/Base/Services.php` (removing all confidential details) (Put it in the original post - the one above this comment - everything below is considered answers)

Comment: paste code from Base/Services.php

Comment: ready!!
I already added friend. It is the same code as the Invo of Phalcon. Nothing is changed. I hope you can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your PHP version and OS? (https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/12056#issuecomment-243447917)

Comment: [ Windows NT DESKTOP-K2F1UCE 10.0 build 14393 (Windows 10) i586 ] => [ PHP version 7.0.15 ] => [ Apache 2.0 Handler ]